# Is it grammatically correct to omit the "to" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

**The British government would pay anyone who could build the best locomotive large sum of money.**

*-or should I say-*

**The British government would pay large sum of money to anyone who could build the best locomotive.**

Comment: Gramatically either sentence works, if you add _" a "_ before _"large."_  I would say "whoever" instead of "anybody", because "anybody" implies the possibility of multiple people, whereas "best" locomotive implies that there will be only one.  So _"anybody who can build a really good train"_ or "whoever can build the **best** train."  But that is less about grammar, and more about style.  The _"a"_ is mandatory, though.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing "a" before "large".

But otherwise both are fully grammatical and idiomatic.

Like many ditransitive verbs, *give* has two possible frames:

> X gives Y to Z
>
> X gives Z Y

These have the same meaning, and in both cases Y is the thing given, Z the recipient.

There is a slight tendency to avoid the second pattern if Z is a long or complicated phrase, because it can make it harder to understand; so your second sentence is probably preferable to your first. But both are OK.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence is ambiguous because of "the best locomotive large sum of money". I would choose the second.

Comment: What is the ambiguity?

Comment: @Adam. It means presence of more than one meaning.

Comment: @theinlwin: you need to pay attention to articles in English! Adam asked you "What is **the** ambiguity?" This is not a question about the meaning of "ambiguity", but asking you to identify the particular ambiguity you claim is there. LIke Adam, I see no ambiguity in the sentence.

Comment: @Colin Fine:thanks for your explanation. But you said that the second pattern can make it harder to understand. So I think it is the ambiguity.

Comment: Ambiguity doesn't just mean "hard to understand."  It means it is hard to understand because there is more than one way that the sentence could be interpreted.

Comment: Adam is right, @theinlwin. [Garden path sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence) are not usually ambiguous, in the end; but the reader may be temporarily misled into thinking the meaning is different, until they reach the point where that interpretation becomes untenable, and they have to go back and parse it again.